# pgool2 watchdog not listening on Virtual IP interface

Tags: watchdog, pgpool

I have set up a pgpool in replication mode with watchdog having a Virtual IP (unused one).
The pgpool and watchdog startup completes successfully.

Virtual eth0:0 interface is created with the specified IP `192.168.143.95`. pgPool is configured to run at port 5432

When trying to connect to the virtual IP:port the psql command `psql -h 192.168.143.95 -p 5432 -l` says 

   `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
   Is the server running on host "192.168.143.95" and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

apparently, there is no listening socket on any port for the virtual ip address. 
Does anybody have a similar working configuration?
Are there some unspecified requirements for the Virtual IP address (like same subnet with pgpool interface) ?

I will be thankful for any suggestions as to why this may not work.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the netmask of the virtual IP as the same range as pg instance. Also make sure you don't have firewall opened.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the command within the network or on the same server?

As mentioned, when not within the node, check if a firewall is blocking the port and be in the same network ( presumably 192.168.143.0/24 ).
Is PgPool actually up and running without errors ?
If it's running on the same machine it would conflict with the standard PostgreSQL port and as such that may be down.
If running on an external node, the PgPool node needs to be able to connect to the postgresql server so the pgpool.conf and pg_hba.conf need to be correct and you may use a .pgpass file.

It seems to me that pgpool cannot connect to postgres if you are sure you are talking to pgpool in your example.
Send a ping or telnet to the postgres server IP to see if there is anything wrong in the network. Pgpool listens on the virtual IP and proxies it to the postgresql host that is registered as primary.

A good example setup can be found here :
https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/example-cluster.html